# Usage Limitations for Google Maps Client Side API in a PhoneGap App

Tags: google-maps, cordova, limits

I have a PhoneGap application that has a Google Map view that drops pins for locations geo-encoded by Google Maps. I’m using the free client-side API since from my understanding each user that installs the app has his/her own usage limits (25k per day), that they will likely never exceed. The app is free, but I was paid to build the app.

If this goes to the app store am I breaking the law? I feel like a PhoneGap mobile application is a gray area since there is no server and no single IP that can abuse the service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure who you did pay.

Anyway, the Google Maps API TOS describes this at `9.1.2 Exceptions > Mobile Applications.`

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1_2

> (b) Mobile Applications.
>
> (i) The rule in Section 9.1.1(a) (Free Access) **does not apply if your Maps API Implementation is used in a mobile application** that is sold for a fee through an online store and is downloadable to a mobile device that can access the online store.

And Google Maps API for work does not work on PhoneGap, because there is no domain.